# Extract specific node value via Firebase Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Ok so I'm going to start with some background (skip to MY ISSUE for tl;dr):

I have an application in development that passes data from a Google Sheet into a Firebase Realtime Database in the form of a 2d Array. The data layout of the Google sheet is as shown below:
[image: Data in the Google Sheet]

This data is passed into a Firebase Realtime Database under the node *masterSheet* via an Apps Script function result shown below:

[image: Data in the Firebase Realtime Database]

Which is used as the live database for my mobile web application I am developing using the Ionic Framework (preview below):

[image: Data as viewed on the Ionic App]

I have functions which deal with the setting of "Y" and "N" flags at the correct positions for the sub tasks of each job and a function which sets the overall job completion status flag to "Y" when all sub tasks are done working as intended.

I am trying to add in an automatic email service via Firebase Cloud Functions that sends off a "job completion notification" whenever a job's overall "Completed" status is set to "Y" (i.e the value at ref: 'masterSheet/0/1' is equal to "Y").

So far I have managed to get it to successfully send off the emails via a Firebase Cloud Function using nodemailer and the Firebase Admin SDK to all registered users of the Firebase app whenever a job's overall completed status is changed from an "N" to a "Y" via the *onUpdate()* method and the *.ref()* of the location to listen at.

Below is my *Index.js* file containing the cloud function I am using:

```js
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// The mail service used
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Cloud Fucntion to export:
exports.onMessageUpdate = functions.database.ref('/masterSheet/{subArray}/1')
  .onUpdate((change) => {
    var changeRef = change.after.ref.path;
    console.log('changeRef: ' + changeRef);
    var newVal = change.after.val();
    if (newVal == "Y"){
      getUsers();
    }
  })

// Fucntion to get all registers users of the Firebase Project
function getUsers(){
  var userEmails = [];
  admin.auth().listUsers()
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        console.log(userRecord);
        userEmails.push(userRecord.email);
        sendCompletionEmail(userRecord.email)
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
}

// Function to send automatic emails
function sendCompletionEmail(email){
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      type: 'OAuth2',
      user: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
      clientId: 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      refreshToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  })

  // Email details:
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxxxxxx',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Job completion notification',
    text: 'This is an automated message to inform you that a job has been fully completed ' + 
    'with all of its tasks marked as done. \n\nYou can view this (along with any others) from the Completed ' +
    'Jobs page within the app.'
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, res) {
    if(err){
        console.log('Error');
    } else {
        console.log('Email Sent');
    }
  })
}
```

MY ISSUE:
I want to be able to include the job title in this automatic email that is sent.

logging the result of *change.after.ref.path* used in the snippet below:

```js
// Cloud Fucntion to export:
exports.onMessageUpdate = functions.database.ref('/masterSheet/{subArray}/1')
  .onUpdate((change) => {
    var changeRef = change.after.ref.path;
    console.log('changeRef: ' + changeRef);
    var newVal = change.after.val();
    if (newVal == "Y"){
      getUsers();
    }
  })
```

Produces this log output:

[image: changeRef console log]

which contains exactly what I want within it... But I don't know how to get it out...

How can I retrieve the second value from the *changeRef* variable so that I can pass this onto the *sendCompletionEmail()* function and use it to refer to the item at position [0] for that node?

something like:

```js
var subArray = changeRef[1]
```

to get the value: 0 out of masterSheet/0/1

which i can store as a variable and use to refer to the job title of the job that has just been completed in the sent off email.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the `0` from the request, that is available from the second parameter that is passed into your Cloud Function (but that you're not declaring).

```
exports.onMessageUpdate = functions.database.ref('/masterSheet/{subArray}/1')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      console.log(context.params.subArray);
  })
```

See the Firebase documentation on [handling event data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) and the reference docs for [`onUpdate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate).